# Getting "Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server"

Tags: python, html, flask, web, deployment

Code:

```py
from cgi import print_exception
from cgitb import text
from flask import Flask, redirect,render_template,request, flash
import joblib
from helpers.dummies1_py import *

app=Flask(__name__)

model=joblib.load('models\model.h5')
scaler=joblib.load('models\scaler.h5')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/predict',methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "opps"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        all_data=   request.args
        Mileage=float(all_data['Mileage'])
        Engine=float(all_data['Engine'])
        Power=float(all_data['Power'])
        Tax=float(all_data['Tax'])
        cars_old=float(all_data['carsold'])  
        miles_driven=float(all_data['miles_driven'])       
        Owner_Type=all_data['Owner_Type']
        Location=all_data['location']
        Fuel_Type=all_data['Fuel_Type']
        Transmission=all_data['transmission']
        Seats=all_data['seats']
        data=[Mileage,Engine,Power,Tax,cars_old,miles_driven]+owner_type_dummies[Owner_Type]+Location_dummies[Location]+Fuel_Type_dummies[Fuel_Type]+Transmission_dummies[Transmission]+seats_dummies[Seats]
        final_data=scaler.transform([data])
        pred=model.predict(final_data)[0]

        return redirect('templates\\prediction.html')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: you are overwriting '/' route. use only one time.

Comment: I made it, but still not working.

Comment: which url did not find ?